# how can i make the footer padding between the sections of my tableView with UITableViewStyle UITableViewStyleGrouped 0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate   = self;
}


- (CGFloat )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 50;
}

- (CGFloat )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 0;
}
```

the `dataSource` returns 3 sections and 2rows per section ,and there is a padding of `40Px` between per section ,I wanna to make the padding zero ;

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
           viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```